# UI for seeing secondary Cards in Match in Marvel Snap

Tags: marvel-snap

When cards are merged or create cards in game the UI shows these 90% hidden under the primary card. Like this;

[image: Vulture + Phoenix]

In the collection screen tapping on the right hand side of the screen moves the secondary, or next in the case of multiples like Nico, to the front. In Match where ever I tap it just seems to send the card back to the table.

How can I see the cards stacked up together during a Match?